# Why is a pointer to a returned reference not possible?

Tags: c++, pointers

Why can't this work? toBeEvolved is a `std::vector,` `.getIndividual` returns an element

```
Individual& EvolutionaryAlgorithm::tournamentSelection(unsigned int i)
{
    return toBeEvolved.getIndividual(i);
}

Individual* in2 = tournamentSelection(0);
```

Compile Time Error: No viable conversion from 'Individual' to 'Individual*'

Comment: References are not pointers. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Im trying to set a pointer to an element through this function.

Comment: I think the fact that references are often implemented as implicit pointers is confusing the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the address of the reference in order to convert it to a pointer.  Even though you may know that the reference is handled as a pointer by the compiler "behind the scenes", there is no explicit requirement in the language that references be implemented as pointer variables, and you will still need to use an explicit `&` operator to tell it you want the address as a pointer.  So:

```
Individual* in2 = &tournamentSelection(0);
```

Other posters have gone into much greater depth on the [distinction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57492/55637) between pointers and references.